# Unable to recover .swp file

Tags: swap-file

My computer crashed while in the middle of editing several vim files. Upon reboot, two of the files getting edited showed a file size 0 bytes. I was able to recover one of the .swp files with the `:recover` command. However, when I try to `:recover` on the other file I get `so swap file found for .Organizer.pm.swp` in the status line even though the file exists.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Is there any data in the swap file? Or is it empty? You can also try recovering from a backup file, if you're storing those somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that `.Organizers.pm.swp` (with an 's' at the end) exists which is another file. The one I need doesn't exist at all.  Hopefully my TimeMachine backed it up recently.

Comment: As a sidenote, personally I use `set backup backupdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/backup`, which results in Vim perpetually keeping backups in the given directory on every write. It has saved a file three or four times from getting lost, not just from computer failures, but also from user errors ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I think I'm screwed. I forgot this file was on a samba share so Time Machine didn't back it up. I don't get what happened, though. Every other file has a .swp file. The computer crashed instantly after I saved it with vim. So something screwy happened.